# copying a directory of repositories to another server

Tags: svn

```
CentOS 5.3
```

I have a directory called repos. Inside that directory I have repositories and subdirectories of repositories. There are more than 30 repositories in all.

We are now moving our repositories to another server. I am just wondering what is the best way to copy all the repositories.

I have looked at svnadmin dump and hotcopy. However, I would like to copy all the repositories recursively. I am not sure that dump and hotcopy allow you to copy all the directories.

I could use hotcopy. However, that would take forever if I have to do them one at a time.

Would it be safe to do a just a normal file copy i.e. `scp -r source dest`

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way.

Which is using rsync. That is what I did and it worked ok.

```
rsync -rcaz -e ssh source@xx.xx.xx.xx:/svn_repos dest@xx.xx.xx.xx:/svn_repos
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can very well do a scp from source to destination. you might just need to make the appropriate configuration/commandline changes while starting svn.

Answer (score 1):

> I could use hotcopy. However, that would take forever if I have to do them one at a time.

You can try to use bash scripting:

`for d in /srv/svnroot/* ; do svnadmin dump $d | ssh targetserver svnadmin load $d ; done`

Where `/srv/svnroot` is your directory with the svn repositories and `targetserver` you new server.

I would not really recommend `scp`, it works only with FSFS repositories and you have to make sure that **nobody** can access them while you copy.